# Can Watch Series 6 be used as a BLE peripheral?

Tags: bluetooth, apple-watch

Is with Series 6 finally possible to use Watch as a Bluetooth LE peripheral?

Edit: clarification: this is about being able to make the Watch available as peripheral programmatically, in apps / with Core Bluetooth.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @jksoegaard to offer services/characteristic to be read and written to.

Comment: I want to understand what you want to achieve here. Are you saying that you want to develop an app that would offer a service/characteristic over BLE to other centrals (i.e. for example a computer)?

Comment: @jksoegaard yup. The iPhone can be used both as central and peripheral. The Watch so far only as central. I'd like to know whether this has changed with Series 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Any change wouldn't have come with the Watch Series 6 as such, but a change in watchOS 7 - but such a change has not been made.

Comment: That's right (though it could be hardware related?). Also, just curious, how do you know this? If I look at the docs, e.g. `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` (which is used only by a peripheral) says `watchOS 4.0+`.

Comment: It’s the right class you have there - you can use that on iOS for example to let the phone work as a Bluetooth peripheral. The class also exists in watchOS, but you’ll find that you cannot get an instance working there. It is currently not supported by Apple on watchOS.

Comment: Ah, you found out by testing the watchOS 7 beta on an older watch. I wonder why they don't allow the watch to be a peripheral.

Comment: But wait, if you find out that it doesn't work at runtime, couldn't it be that it's hardware related and it works on the Series 6?

Comment: It doesn’t work on the Series 6.

Comment: Sorry for insisting, just curious: how do you know (since it was released 2 days ago, and by your profile location, it seems unlikely that you already have one)?

Comment: The software is downloadable now no matter where you are in the world.

Comment: But why are you sure that it will not work on a different hardware? I believe advertising to be (too) a hardware capability, so it could work on some devices not on others, with the same OS?

Comment: You would that in the software if it were the case. It has also been tested with the actual hardware.

Comment: Not sure I follow. The same software could offer different capabilities, depending on the hardware on which is run. Maybe there's a misunderstanding. Anyway, thanks for answering.

Comment: If you look at the code, such functionality is evident. I.e. you’ll see in the code that if it checks if hardware X is available or hardware Y is available and then does different things.

Comment: To my knowledge the majority of WatchOS source code is closed. What code are you talking about?

Comment: You do not need need to look at the source code. How to disassemble frameworks is a bit beyond what can be explained in a comment here, I'm afraid. Please note that I don't have any "tricks" for you on how to circumvent this limitation in watchOS.